# Php and Xpath - how to get text from inside a node

Tags: php, xpath

How how can I get a text from inside a node using xpath?

For now I'm doing it like this:

```
$temp= $content->xpath('qwe/qwe');
$temp = each($temp[0]);
return $temp['value'];
```

But as you can see it's far from good solution :(

In c# it is as easy as

```
public string readXmlVar(string xpath)
{
    XmlNode xmlNode = xml.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
    return xmlNode.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: Just cast it as a string: `return (string) $temp;`

Comment: hm, that works :) Why didn't you wrote proper reply? I'd plus'ed you and selected your answer :)

Comment: php can be such a crazy language sometimes... you can never know what to do in some cases...

Comment: possible duplicate of [obtain the node value as text with php + xpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383355/obtain-the-node-value-as-text-with-php-xpath)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For `SimleXmlElement` just cast it as a string: `return (string) $temp;`. For `DomDocument` use `return $temp->nodeValue`.

Comment: One has to be careful thoguh, using `$temp->nodeValue` for `DomDocument` will return the text content from all children below the given node (including children of children).

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML('<root>
    <p>some text<br />some more text</p>
</root>');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('/root/p/text()') as $textNode) {
    echo $textNode->nodeValue;
}
```

`$textNode` will be a [DOMText](http://php.net/manual/class.domtext.php).

Comment: @Lurler Why? If you want all text content, just collect the node values. This is simple dom traversing, it's not even php specific.

Comment: Because it creates copy of the variable and then iterates over it. It's completely ineffecient.

Comment: Are you sure that is the case when you are dealing with objects? By nature isnt it a reference?

Comment: @prodigitalson To be honets, the way Lurler is responding on this topic, I don't thinks it makes much sense to discuss this any further.

Comment: @Yoshi: yes, premature micro-optimizers are an interesting breed ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
(string) current($xml->xpath("//group[@ref='HS_TYP']"))
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Much better. A simple and complete one-line solution to a simple question.

Answer (score 2):

This will get all inner text from simple xml element

```
dom_import_simplexml($xpath->query('//div[@class="h1"]')->textContent;
```

Comment: OMG thank you - search a long while for this small command 